# How to iterate through $_POST to update multiple recordsets in DB via PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO and associative arrays but am making good progress. I've set up this code to save a html form to a single recordset:

```
$str_sql = "UPDATE tbl_benutzer SET ";
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        if($key=='id'){continue;}
        $str_sql .= $key." = :".$key.", ";
    }
    $str_sql = substr($str_sql,0,-2)." WHERE id = :id";

    ///////SAVE DATA TO DB///////
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($str_sql);
    $stmt->execute($_POST);
```

Now I want to adapt the same code to save the contents of a html form to multiple recordsets. Here's the HTML:

```
<input name="id[]" value="1">
<input name="tarif[]" value="A">
<input name="mitgliedschaft[]" value="X">
<input name="gebuehr[]" value="100">

<input name="id[]" value="2">
<input name="tarif[]" value="B">
<input name="mitgliedschaft[]" value="Y">
<input name="gebuehr[]" value="200">

<input name="id[]" value="3">
<input name="tarif[]" value="C">
<input name="mitgliedschaft[]" value="Z">
<input name="gebuehr[]" value="300">
```

And here's the $_POST array:

```
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 ) 
[tarif] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C ) 
[mitgliedschaft] => Array ( [0] => X [1] => Y [2] => Z ) 
[gebuehr] => Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 200 [2] => 300 ) )
```

This is what I've tried so far but my head's just not getting around it!:

```
$str_sql = "UPDATE tbl_stamm_tarif SET ";
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        if($key=='id'){continue;}
        $str_sql .= $key." = :".$key.", ";
    }
    $str_sql = substr($str_sql,0,-2)." WHERE id = :id";
    echo $str_sql;

    ///////SAVE DATEN TO DB///////
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($str_sql);
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        foreach($value as $key2=>$value2){
            $stmt->execute(array($key=>$value2));
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider changing your HTML structure to something like:

```
<input name="**model_name**[**id1**][tarif]" value="A">
<input name="**model_name**[**id1**][mitgliedschaft]" value="X">
<input name="**model_name**[**id1**][gebuehr]" value="100">

<input name="**model_name**[**id2**][tarif]" value="B">
<input name="**model_name**[**id2**][mitgliedschaft]" value="Y">
<input name="**model_name**[**id2**][gebuehr]" value="200">
```

(for an `UPDATE` page you shouldn't really be allowed to change the `id`)

That way you can just iterate through the models as:

```
foreach($_POST['**model_name**'] as $id=>$model){}
```

and perform the `UPDATE` on each iteration as before.

**UPDATE**

I'd also be wary of your code as it is hugely vulnerable to SQL injection.. you should really check the value of each `$key` against the known columns before spanking straight it into a statement. Otherwise the user can submit their own `$key` and open up your database.

**UPDATE 2**

Either pull the columns from the database, or hard code them into whatever PHP model class you are using as an array (saves a trip, but needs doing if you change the schema).

I'd probably assign the values to a keyed array in the model class from the `$_POST` array before running the SQL, as you may need them later.

**N.B.**

A lot of these issues have already been solved in the various frameworks out there; no idea what your project is (could be writing a framework) but for anyone stumbling across this frameworks can save a lot of work and security vulnerabilities!

Comment: Thanks. Works a treat! What do you think is the better way to stop foreign injection? 1.get column names from DB and compare them with the keys, or 2.just get column names from DB and build the sql statement from there.

Comment: @RichardTinkler NP. See update :) Oh, and please accept if you use this answer!

Comment: Thanks Arth. Sounds like I'm re-inventing the wheel! Which frameworks would you recommend for simple selecting, updating, and inserting?

Comment: @RichardTinkler I use Yii for work, but there are plenty more out there.. have a google!